# How to fix this git error in Webstorm 9.0.2 updating changes:fatal..?

Tags: windows, git, webstorm

I had a similar error in windows 7 in the command line. This was fixed by setting a new config location for git. See [how to change gitconfig location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690019/how-to-change-gitconfig-location).

When I crank up my webstorm however and check the localchanges panel at the bottom of the IDE it says:

```
Error updating changes: fatal: unable to access'H:/\/.config/git/config' Invalid argument during executing git -c core.quotepath=false status --porcelain -z --untracked-files=no --
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a variable "HOMEDRIVE" or "HOME" set to H:. Setting the environment variable

HOME=%USERPROFILE%

solved it for me.