# How to update git location on windows 10 after changing windows user-name?

Tags: git, github

I just changed my windows user name.
now when I want to update my e-mail on git using:

`git config --global user.email "my_email@gmail.com"`

I'm getting this message: error: 
`Could not lock config file C:/Users/"MY OLD WINDOWS USER-NAME"/AppData/Roaming/SPB_Data/.gitconfig: No such file or directory.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35063493/changing-the-git-username

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change gitconfig location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690019/how-to-change-gitconfig-location)